# Java Socket I/O Streams Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, sockets

I've got a simple client and server that I've written to teach myself a bit of networking. The way it's set up is I've got a main server class which will deal with creating/destroying sockets, and the ConnectionThread class that represents each connection (each of which is given its own thread). The client is super simple.

The problem lies in creating the input/output streams in the ConnectionThread class. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but it crashes when the simple test client tries to connect, giving me this:

```
~~MMO Server Alpha .1~~
Constructed Server
Server Initialized, preparing to start...
Server preparing to check if it should be listening...
Server should be listening, continuing as planned.
ServerSocket passed to ConnectionThread: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=6969]
Constructing ConnectionThread.
Socket[addr=/10.0.1.10,port=55332,localport=6969]
ConnectionThread constructed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConnectionThread.init(ConnectionThread.java:65)
    at Server.listen(Server.java:98)
    at Server.start(Server.java:62)
    at Server.main(Server.java:122)
ConnectionThread added to queue.
Establishing in and out streams:
null
```

Here are the classes (amended for brevity):

```
public class Server {
    int PORT;
    boolean shouldListen;
    ArrayList<ConnectionThread> connections = new ArrayList<ConnectionThread>();
    ServerSocket serverSocket;



    public Server() {

        try {
            PORT = 6969;
            shouldListen = true;
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Error in server constructor.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }



    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Server preparing to check if it should be listening...");
        listen();
        System.out.println("Server finished listening.");
    }


    public void listen() {
        while (shouldListen) {
            ConnectionThread conn = null;
            System.out.println("Server should be listening, continuing as planned.");
            try {
            conn = new ConnectionThread(serverSocket);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("____Error constructing ConnectionThread. Could there be another instance of the server running?");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            System.out.println("ConnectionThread constructed.");

            connections.add(conn);
            System.out.println("ConnectionThread added to queue.");

            conn.init();
            System.out.println("Finished ConnectionThread initialization, verifying...");

            if (conn.isInitialized) {
                System.out.println("ConnectionThread Initialized, preparing to start new thread.");
                (new Thread(conn)).start();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("~~MMO Server Alpha .1~~");
        Server server = new Server();
        System.out.println("Constructed Server");
        server.init();
        System.out.println("Server Initialized, preparing to start...");
        server.start();

    }

}
```

Here's the ConnectionThread class:

```
public class ConnectionThread implements Runnable {
    boolean shouldBeListening = true;
    boolean isThereAnUnsentOutgoingMessage = false;
    String outgoingMessage = "OUTGOING UNINITIALIZED";
    boolean IsThereAnUnsentIncomingMessage = false;
    String incomingMessage = "INCOMING UNITIALIZED";
    boolean isInitialized = false;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    String currentInputMessage = "Test Input Message from the Server ConnectionThread";
    String previousInputMessage = null;


    Socket socket;





    public ConnectionThread(ServerSocket s) {
        System.out.println("ServerSocket passed to ConnectionThread: " + s);
        /*
         * The purpose of the constructor is to establish a socket
         * as soon as possible. All transmissions/logic/anything else
         * should happen in init() and/or run().
         */
        System.out.println("Constructing ConnectionThread.");
        try {
        Socket socket = s.accept();
        System.out.println(socket);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in ConnectionThread constructor");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }




    public void init() {
        /*
         * Everything should be set up here before run is called.
         * Once init is finished, run() should be set to begin work.
         * This is to ensure each packet is efficiently processed.
         */
        try {
            System.out.println("Establishing in and out streams:");
            System.out.println(socket);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("ConnectionThread: Output Stream (PrintWriter) Established");

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("ConnectionThread: InputStream (BufferedReader) Established");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in ConnectionThread method Init.");
            System.exit(1);
        }



        isInitialized = true;
    }
```

And optionally, here's the test client:

```
public class TestClient {
    static PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    public final int PORT = 6969;
    Socket socket = null;
    InetAddress host = null;

    public TestClient() {
        out = null;
        in = null;
        socket = null;
        host = null;



    }



    public void connectToServer() {
        System.out.println("Connecting to server...");
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error establishing host/socket");
            System.exit(1);
        }




        try {
            System.out.println("Establishing I/O Streams");
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error establishing in/out streams");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("~~TestClient Alpha .1~~");
        TestClient c = new TestClient();
        c.connectToServer();
        System.out.println("Should be connected to server. Sending test message...");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("here");
            out.println("Hello there");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'socket' variable in the constructor of ConnectionThread shouldn't be local. It is shadowing the member variable.

It is customary to call accept() in the listen() loop, and pass the accepted socket to the ConnectionThread.

Comment: Oh, man. What an oversight. Thank you so much for pointing that out. The kindness and helpfulness of StackOverflow never ceases to amaze.

Answer (score 1):

As [EJP said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19459895/97627), in your ConnectionThread constructor you think that you are assigning the value to the `socket` field, however you are actually assigning the value to the `socket` method variable, thus the `socket` field remains null, and in `init()` you see `socket` as null.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to EJP answer: you did not provide ConnectionThread.run() method, but I assume you are going to use fields `in`, `out` and `socket` in your `run()` method. Since these fields are not marked as `volatile` or `final`, depending on your luck and number of core on your computer, you may also get NullPointerException at run() method.

This is because new variable value may be not propagated between caches and new thread will not see value of changed.

Explanation of this possible problem is here - [The code example which can prove "volatile" declare should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816790/the-code-example-which-can-prove-volatile-declare-should-be-used)

Comment: Thank you, didn't realized thread start creates _happens before_.