# Will volatile fix this Multi-Thread Code?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I have two threads updating a shared `int` at the same time. Most of times, this code will print `0` and `1`. But some times, it will print `0` and `0` (one update failed). If I make the `int value` `volatile`, will fix that update fail, once for all?

This is not a Home-Work question, really. I just wrote these code and this question, like if was, to clarify my understanding of Java Memory Model. I read [this Article](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/Concurrency,+Visibility,+and+Memory).

I know this code will be fixed in a `synchronized` way, but this is not the scope of question, is just about the volatile will fix or not, and why.

```
    public class Testes{

    public static int value = 0;

    public static void main(String ... args) {

        T t = new T();
        T t2 = new T();

        t.start();
        t2.start();

    }

}

class T extends Thread{

    public void update(){
        System.out.println(Testes.value++);
    }

    public void run(){
        this.update();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried testing your code by setting int value volatile?

Comment: @santaunu yes, but really, you must run lots of times. I don't know if I run so much times to see if it will fix, or not. To get this 0 and 0 result, I run around 450 times... LOL!

Comment: @yngwietiger I'm not sure, because you have the Java Memory Model, and `volatile` will fix the Java Memory Model problem, but the process of `value++` is not atomic and it can be broken in more, and the thread 1 will race with thread 2

Comment: @yngwietiger , yes, I probably will never use `volatile`, but this is more about learning the Java Memory Model. I found this question on where to use the `volatile`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816790/the-code-example-which-can-prove-volatile-declare-should-be-used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I make the int value volatile, will fix that update fail, once for all?

No.  The issue you are seeing is almost certainly not related to memory inconsistency.  The failure is because of atomicity.  It is widely known `++` operator is not atomic (it is actually three operations).  There is plenty of information you can read on about it.

Comment: Did you know where can I found a good example of this situation where `volatile` will fix the problem? A example code. tnx!

Comment: Well, unfortunately `volatile` cannot fix this problem for you.  It can only deal with a single operation. If you really want to resolve this you can either use `synchronized` (as you mentioned) or the more appropriate `AtomicInteger` class.  The `AtomicInteger` can be `final` so you could completely disregard `volatile` in that case.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But I meant a code situation, an example, where I will put the `volatile` and will fix. A code example.. I googled, but i don't found

Comment: I have found! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816790/the-code-example-which-can-prove-volatile-declare-should-be-used

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John for clarifying the same...

When you execute System.out.println(Testes.value++) what happens is
it is a postfix operation for increment...so the println is done
first and then value gets incremented...thats why you see 0 by
the first thread..but after the println is done its execution
the value is now 1 ..that is why the second thread shows 1 when
it prints the value ....